# Filtering out blank rows from {} in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a series of `QUERY` formulae which are joined together using `{}` syntax in google spreadsheets.

For example:

```
={
        IFNA( QUERY('Week 1'!A2:Z33,"select Z, B, D, E where A = 'Bench Press' and D IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } );
        IFNA( QUERY('Week 1'!A2:Z33,"select Z, F, H, I where A = 'Bench Press' and H IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } );
        IFNA( QUERY('Week 1'!A2:Z33,"select Z, J, L, M where A = 'Bench Press' and L IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } );
        IFNA( QUERY('Week 1'!A2:Z33,"select Z, N, P, Q where A = 'Bench Press' and P IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } );
        IFNA( QUERY('Week 1'!A2:Z33,"select Z, R, T, U where A = 'Bench Press' and T IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } )
}
```

If the query does not find a result for the specific columns it returns `{"","","",""}` so that the `{}` does not break with mismatched data. As additional weeks are added, I add more rows to pull in the extra data so that I have a single sheet containing all workout data for "Bench Press" that I can process.

**The problem is, this results in blank rows. How do I eliminate the blank rows using formulae without changing the structure of the `Week 1` sheet or using scripts?**

e.g.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, wrap the `{}` in a `Query` formula that tests column 1 if it's null:

```
=QUERY( {
        IFNA( QUERY({'Week 1'!A2:Z33;'Week 2'!A2:Z33;'Week 3'!A2:Z33},"select Col26, Col2,  Col4,  Col5  where Col1 = 'Bench Press' and Col4  IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } );
        IFNA( QUERY({'Week 1'!A2:Z33;'Week 2'!A2:Z33;'Week 3'!A2:Z33},"select Col26, Col6,  Col8,  Col9  where Col1 = 'Bench Press' and Col8  IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } );
        IFNA( QUERY({'Week 1'!A2:Z33;'Week 2'!A2:Z33;'Week 3'!A2:Z33},"select Col26, Col10, Col12, Col13 where Col1 = 'Bench Press' and Col12 IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } );
        IFNA( QUERY({'Week 1'!A2:Z33;'Week 2'!A2:Z33;'Week 3'!A2:Z33},"select Col26, Col14, Col16, Col17 where Col1 = 'Bench Press' and Col16 IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } );
        IFNA( QUERY({'Week 1'!A2:Z33;'Week 2'!A2:Z33;'Week 3'!A2:Z33},"select Col26, Col18, Col20, Col21 where Col1 = 'Bench Press' and Col20 IS NOT NULL", 0), { "","","","" } )
}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL" )
```

I also simplified the original queries input to avoid more `QUERY` calls, and as a bonus, I can sort the entire output using the outer `QUERY`